# Bound surface current density on rotating sphere.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, physics, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

For solid sphere of radius R, azimuthal angle $\phi$ and polar angle $\theta$ rotating at velocity $\vec{v}$ with uniform surface charge $\sigma$ ,

the bound surface current density is

$\vec{K}=\sigma \omega R \sin(\theta)\hat{\phi}$

I'm curious as to why $\vec{v}=\omega R \sin(\theta)\hat{\phi}$

I understand why the $\hat{\phi}$ exists.

Any physical insights into the formulation of the above expression is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\vec K$ is a vector field, $\sigma\omega R \sin(\theta)$ is a scalar, $\hat \phi$ is an angular unit vector deciding in what direction that scalar points.

Comment: The surface has a charge. The charge moves when the surface rotates. A current is moving electrical charges. Although probably the physics related aspects of the question is better for physics.stackexchange.

Comment: I think I got it.
Thanks for the suggestion but question of such nature are not allowed according to Physics stack.@mathreadler